# Home app unavailable devices

Tags: smart-home, apple-homekit

With iOS home app, I’m seeing that all the devices on a particular bridge sometimes go offline until I restart my HomePod Mini. I know they’re not offline, since the HomePod turns them on or off with automations, so it must be related to iOS.

It isn’t all the devices or bridges; it’s not always the same ones; it isn’t all the time either. Force closing the app or restarting the phone doesn’t make any difference.

Any ideas why it might be happening and/or how to solve it? Or how to get the home app to refresh it’s database?